# Any online tools for SVG creating?

Tags: icon, svg

I am looking a free source for creating SVG icons, any provide or example for me?

Thanks.

Comment: https://vectr.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a form of shopping question, which is off topic for StackExchange sites

Answer (score 2):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/download/) is an opensource app for creating vector graphics just like Illustrator, and it can export SVG files.

Comment: Not only export. SVG is the native format :o)